# Eval() Interprter return null

Tags: java, android

I am working on Mobile app calcluator 
I am trying to evaluate a string as a math equation by using "bsh" library.
Successfully, I imported the library and compiled.

When I try to implement this part under the equal sign I am getting null all the time

```
equSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              String value = "";
              Double result= null;
                  Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
              try {
                     result = (Double)interpreter.eval(input);
                  } catch (EvalError evalError) {
                      evalError.printStackTrace();
                  }
              value = String.valueOf(result);
              text.setText(value);
          }
      });
```

every time the user pree 0 to 9 numbers or . or any opertion + / - *
it will be added to input variable

```
  Num0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          text.setText(text.getText()+"0");
          input = input + "0";
      }
  });
```

this function for all other buttons

I used try catch as well to catch an error

Comment: Everything is working fine except the equal sign

Answer (score 2):

Your issue appears to be that you're mixing variables of your java class and your 'bsh' interpreter. Basically bsh cannot access your java variables directly and you need to set them in the interpreter.

`i.eval(input)` is probably what you meant to do.

Take a look at the examples in http://www.beanshell.org/javadoc/bsh/Interpreter.html to see how some other features are used.

Comment: It does not work and I am really confused how to use eval and het passing variable from my program

Comment: @Hemm Looking at the documentation, the call should probably be `i.eval("value=<whatever formula you want to calculate>")`.
The result should then be available as `i.get("value")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, you are passing in the "input" as a string for eval to evaluate which it can't because it is just a string not the actual numeric expression you are trying to evaluate.

```
public static void bsh() throws EvalError {

    String expression = "input=2+2-5";
    String value = " ";
    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();




    try {
        i.eval(expression);
    } catch (EvalError evalError) {
        evalError.printStackTrace();
    }

    value = String.valueOf((Integer)i.get("input"));
    System.out.println(value);

}
```

Alternativley if you want to do it the way you had you can get the return value directly from eval as per below:

```
 public static void bsh() throws EvalError {

    String input = "2+2-5";
    String value = " ";
    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();



Integer result = null;
    try {
        result = (Integer)i.eval(input);
    } catch (EvalError evalError) {
        evalError.printStackTrace();
    }

    value = String.valueOf(result);
    System.out.println(value);

}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Comment: Still I am getting null when I try to pass the input. Thank you

Comment: Can you provide your full code sample pls? I just compile both of the above methods and they returned the correct value of '-1'.

Comment: equSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              String value = "";
              Double result= null;
                  Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
              try {
                     result = (Double)interpreter.eval(input);
                  } catch (EvalError evalError) {
                      evalError.printStackTrace();
                  }
              value = String.valueOf(result);
              text.setText(value);
          }
      });

Comment: Actually when I try to pass "2+2" it works for the second method you use but when I try to pass "input" or input it gives me null point

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all the android code as I can't test easily if your OnClick listener's etc are working. However I have taken the code which is using the bsh interpreter as you will see below and I have run it as a test and it works. I do not know what your input string is therefore I have add an input string you can see it "2.0+2.0-5.0" to show that it works - note it has to to be a double value "2.0" not an integer "2" as you are trying to retrieve a Double result in your code. You should be able to take my method and test it and you will see it will work.

```
 public static void bsh2() {

        String input = "2.0+2.0-5.0";
        String value = "";
        Double result= null;
        Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
        try {
            result = (Double)interpreter.eval(input);
        } catch (EvalError evalError) {
                evalError.printStackTrace();
        }
        value = String.valueOf(result);
        System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help

Comment: Have you tried my code as a stand alone method this will help you see if the issue is elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I tried and I did something like this just to check an still I am getting null

Comment: Very odd all my examples have worked perfectly for me. I am using bsh version: bsh-2.0b4

Comment: equSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              String value = "";
              Integer result= null;
                  Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
              try {
                     result = (Integer)interpreter.eval("2+2");
                  } catch (EvalError evalError) {
                      evalError.printStackTrace();
                  }
              value = String.valueOf(result);
              text.setText(value);
          }
      });

Comment: If you want to send me a simple method you have tried without android code I can verify that for you? Even be ter if you write a simple pure java main and send me that.

Comment: I am writing the code in Android and I think there is a problem in passing string local variable n Android studio may be

Comment: Yes I am pretty certain the issue is in the android code  I know the bsh samples I have provided work :). If you want to +1 them feel free.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try to find the error thanks for help